# Is it good practice to use Table of Contents on articles?

Tags: website-design, best-practice

I was wondering if using some kind of a Table of Contents for an article that consists of different parts, is considered to be good practice.
Enabling users to move to the part that interests them the most seemed like a good idea to me, however I don't really see it implemented very often and there must be a reason for this.

Do you know why or under which circumstances something like this should be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of articles: those that should be read from start-to-finish and those that can be read in chunks or where blocks of information can safely be ignored without compromising information later on. Into which category does your content fall? What is the purpose of the user's visit?

We know that users on the web tend to scan and not read. We also know that headings are great tools to divide up long pages and articles as long as they clearly indicate the hierarchy and describe what follows.

I suspect the lack of a table of contents in most articles has more to do with the desire to maximize engagement and time on page and less to do with usability issues.

I've been experimenting with exactly what you describe in some technical documentation and although I don't have enough data to be sure, initial reception has been very good. People do use these TOC links a large minority of the time.

This feature might not always be appropriate but as a rule, desriptive labelling and excellent wayfinding are almost always beneficial to a user experience.

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap uses it to quickly navigate within their documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

I think it can be really useful on long articles.

Maybe you could also indicate an estimate of how much time is needed to read to the bottom of the article from the current position?